# numberOfRowsInSection is causing unrecognized selector crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, unrecognized-selector

I have a UITableView setup within my view controller to populate with the JSON data that's being returned by a function. When I load MatchCenterViewController, the app crashes and I receive the following error:

```
2014-06-07 15:56:23.651 Parse+Storyboard[6848:607] -[UIView tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xaa29730
2014-06-07 15:56:23.825 Parse+Storyboard[6848:607] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xaa29730'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x02a8c1e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0264a8e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x02b29243 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x02a7c50b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x02a7c0ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   UIKit                               0x0156f94c -[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:] + 2510
    6   UIKit                               0x0157323d -[UITableViewRowData numberOfRows] + 98
    7   UIKit                               0x013f0df2 -[UITableView noteNumberOfRowsChanged] + 120
    8   UIKit                               0x013f07a5 -[UITableView reloadData] + 814
    9   UIKit                               0x013f43b3 -[UITableView _reloadDataIfNeeded] + 65
    10  UIKit                               0x013f95f4 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 36
    11  UIKit                               0x01379964 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 355
    12  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0265c82b -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    13  QuartzCore                          0x0064f45a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
    14  QuartzCore                          0x00643244 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    15  QuartzCore                          0x006430b0 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 26
    16  QuartzCore                          0x005a97fa _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 294
    17  QuartzCore                          0x005aab85 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 393
    18  QuartzCore                          0x006685b0 +[CATransaction flush] + 52
    19  UIKit                               0x013089bb _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 13095
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x02a1577f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x02a1510b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x02a321ae __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x02a319d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x02a317eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    25  GraphicsServices                    0x02ce95ee GSEventRunModal + 192
    26  GraphicsServices                    0x02ce942b GSEventRun + 104
    27  UIKit                               0x0130af9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    28  Parse+Storyboard                    0x00002cbd main + 141
    29  libdyld.dylib                       0x038e56d9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I've checked `UIView tableView:numberOfRowsInSection` that the error code refers to, and I don't see what could be causing this, as it simply tells it that there are 3 rows. Code and screenshots are below.

MatchCenterViewController.m:

```
#import "MatchCenterViewController.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MatchCenterViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *matchCenter;
@end

@implementation MatchCenterViewController



- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}






- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 3;
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *matchCenterDictionary= [self.matchCenterArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [matchCenterDictionary objectForKey:@"Title"];// title of the first object

    //    if([matchCenterDictionary objectForKey:@"Price"] != NULL)
    //    {
    //        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@",[matchCenterDictionary   objectForKey:@"Price"]];
    //    }

    return cell;


}





- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

self.matchCenterArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];

    //perform search with criteria just submitted
    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"MatchCenterTest"
                       withParameters:@{
                                        @"test": @"Hi",
                                        }
                                block:^(NSDictionary *result, NSError *error) {




                                    if (!error) {
                                        self.matchCenterArray = [result objectForKey:@"Top 3"];



                                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                            [_matchCenter reloadData];
                                        });



                                        NSLog(@"Test Result: '%@'", result);

                                    }
                                }];


}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{


    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"MatchCenterTest"
                       withParameters:@{
                                        @"test": @"Hi",
                                        }
                                block:^(NSDictionary *result, NSError *error) {

                                    if (!error) {
                                         self.matchCenterArray = [result objectForKey:@"Top 3"];


                                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                            [_matchCenter reloadData];
                                        });


                                        NSLog(@"Test Result: '%@'", result);
                                    }
                                }];



}




- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}




/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You're setting the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` of your tableView to the `UIView` and not your `MatchCenterViewController` in interface builder.

`UIView` doesn't implement `UITableViewDataSource` and that's why you are getting an unrecognized selector error.

Comment: Ahh I see. I'm a bit confused regarding how I can change this. Is this something I'd change in storyboard, or in the implementation file? I've tried changing the class of the tableview to `MatchCenterViewController` in the storyboard settings, but it keeps reverting back to `UITableView`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `delegate` and `dataSource` to the class that implements the delegate methods. In your case, that's your `MatchCenterViewController`.

Also another thing I notice, you're calling the `PFCloud` method both on `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear`. You should only do that in one place, if you want it to execute one, add it to the `viewDidLoad`, if you want it to execute every time the `view` is shown, add it to `viewDidAppear`.

And another small thing: You should have methods in the order from top to bottom (in your file):

1. dealloc (if you have one)
2. initializer methods (`init`, `initWithFrame`, etc.)
3. Other methods, the related ones grouped up, usually separated with `#pragma mark`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set *MatchCenterViewController* class as *dataSource* and *delegate* for your *matchCenter* table view.

Add following 2 lines of code in `initWithNibName` function

```
[matchCenter setDelegate:self];

[matchCenter setDataSource:self];
```